# Gatsby React app error Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in development environment

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Every time I install a new dependency with npm it's like cutting the read wire and hoping the bomb doesn't go off.

This error keeps coming up now:

> [BABEL]  React Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in
> development environment. Instead, the environment is: "dev_local". If
> you want to override this check, pass {skipEnvCheck: true} as plugin
> options.

It's a Gatsby app and I can't figure out how or where to achieve `{skipEnvCheck: true}` I've tried various things in `gatsby-node.js` such as:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, plugins }) => {

  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        skipEnvCheck: true,
      }),
    ],
  });
};
```

But it doesn't help. I have different development `.env` configs (e.g. this "dev_local" environment) for testing with different settings and I want to keep doing that.

Or am I just chasing ghosts here and really there is some other problem with the dependencies?

Comment: In your gatsby-config.js do you have the "react-refresh" plugin?

Comment: Are you attempting to set a NODE_ENV that is not `development` while running `gatsby develop` or `production` when running `gatsby build`? If so, that's the problem—Gatsby has specific environments hardcoded. You'll want to use another approach to feature flagging or adjusting env config.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error when attempting to deploy a Gatsby app to Heroku. A frustrating rabbit hole ensued, but I eventually narrowed the fix down to using `gatsby serve` instead of the default `gatsby develop` for the start script.

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gatsby serve --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: This was what i needed! Spent too much of time trying to figure out why Heroku and Gatsby weren't playing along.